# How do I add additional data to a DataGridRowGroupHeader?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-3.0

I have a `DataGrid` that is showing some data via a `PagedCollectionView` with one group definition. I have created a `Style` for the corresponding `DataGridRowGroupHeader` under which I have added a `ControlTemplate` containing an additional `TextBlock` and a spacing `Rectangle`. I would like to bind the widths of these controls to the widths of particular columns, but I am struggling to get this working. I would also like to bind the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` to a value.

I tried binding the widths via the `Width` property of a  `Rectangle` in resources but this didn't work (possibly because the `Rectangle` was never drawn and therefore didn't calculate it's layout).

However, I believe both sets of bindings can be performed with some use of one or more `ValueConverter` implementations, but I was wondering if there was a better way. Can any of this be achieved through the definition of a `ControlTemplate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error I was able to customize my row group headers. The key to unlocking the solution involved both the `RowGroupHeaderStyles` property and the `LoadingRowGroup` event on the `DataGrid`.

By defining one or more styles for the groups, I was able to customize the control template to include additional named elements. I then used the event to gain access to those elements and either set or bind the relevant values to show the information I required. The only stumbling I had related to binding the size of controls, which I eventually worked around by saving a reference to each row and setting those sizes when it was necessary to refresh them rather than relying on bindings. This may be specific to my project so your mileage may vary.

**Update**
[JDM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717623/jdm) asked how you get the controls to perform binding etc. in the `LoadingRowGroup` event handler. You can get the row header from the `DataGridRowGroupHeaderEventArgs.RowGroupHeader` property of the event arguments and then use the [`VisualTreeHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to get the child controls of the header. Once you have the controls, you can bind to them in code as you would any other control.

Comment: Originally asked by JDM: Jeff, how do you access those elements (e.g. ToogleButton or Textblock) and either set or bind the relevant values to show the information you required, in the LoadingRowGroup event?

Comment: How do you get header property value in LoadingRowGroup.Could you please your code.

Comment: @HukmChand: Sorry about that, I had written the incorrect information. I've corrected it.